# android service problem

Tags: android, service, boot

i have a problem with a simple service. the service should run "automatically", as i already know if boot completet.
i've found a simple example and my code is the same but it doesnt work, there is nothing in the log. here is the example [Start Service at Boot][1]

```
package com.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainService extends Service
{
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService -- onStart()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService Destroyed");
    }

}


  [1]: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/
```

here the braodcast receiver for the Boot-completed Action:

```
package com.service;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Log.i("Test", "Test");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.service.MainService");
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and here the manifest file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.service"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-        permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <service android:name="com.service.MainService">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action  android:name="android.action.intent.BOOT_COMPLETED">   
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

<receiver android:name="com.service.MainServiceReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
        </action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
        </category>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
```

in the android error log there is always this error:

> 9009  Applications Change Receiver  updating1 application packageName = com.service....

please help me i think its a little thing but I dont see the mistake.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.service.MainService");
context.startService(i);
```

But at in `manifest` you have not declared `intent-filter` to receive this action.

Comment: do mean this?
`<receiver android:name="com.service.MainServiceReceiver">     <intent-filter>         <action android:name="com.service.MainServiceReceiver">         </action>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">         </category>     </intent-filter> </receiver> `

Comment: your service doesnt listen to 'com.service.MainService' actions; either add the action 'com.service.Mainservice' to the service intent filter or call i.setClassName(context, Mainservice.class) before the startService call instead of i.setAction('com.service.Mainservice')

Comment: you mean it should look like this
Manifest:
    `  <service android:name="com.service.MainService">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.service.MainService"> 
    </action>
   </intent-filter>
  </service>`

Comment: and the onReceive method

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
  {  
   context.startService(intent);
   Log.i("Test", "Test");
   
  }
 }

Comment: oh haha forget the last post thats nonsense.
i've got it thank you ! I added the action in the manifest file and in the onReceive method I let the setAction
thanks (;

Answer (score 0):

You only need startSerice by call:
startService(new Intent(MainServiceReceiver .this,MainService.class));
If you have any problem, please add my yahoo or skype :fsoft_duonghv

Comment: if I insert this line, eclipse says that the constructor for Intent() is undefined for the type MainServiceReceiver..

Comment: The first parameter is Context.So MainServiceReceiver.this is ok.